# Parallax from Materialize no showing image

Tags: css, parallax, materialize

Im using Materialize CSS and im trying to use the Parallax.

I followed the instructions: http://materializecss.com/parallax.html

But when i save, no image is shown.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/wecarrasco/pen/qmxMox

```
    <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/landscape-georgia.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section white">
    <div class="row container">
      <h2 class="header">Parallax</h2>
      <p class="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">Parallax is an effect where the background content or image in this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="\wecarrasco.github.io/computer.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.parallax').parallax();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallax not working in materialize css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232539/parallax-not-working-in-materialize-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are working fine now. Here is the link to my demo, which i forked from yours `https://codepen.io/nirajtech/pen/jmKNpr`

The problem was you didn't include the two js file required to trigger the parallax. first one **jquery** and second is **materialize.js**

The link of both js is provided below:

1. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js`
2. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js`

Remeber to include jquery first and then materialize otherwise you will face problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the only fix was that I had was to add a `z-index: X;` with `X` being a number higher then the surround div elements z-index so I set to `15` to the parallax div, so my finishing div was this

```
<div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax" style="z-index: 15;">
        <img src="img/profile2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This made my image appear
I inspected the demo in the documentation in chrome

`<div class="parallax"><img src="images/cow.jpg" style="transform: translate3d(-50%, 432.451px, 0px);opacity: 1;"></div>`